# Is this a correct proof of the closure proposition for subsets of a powerset?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

The following is taken from a set of lecture notes found here
[Lecture Notes 1: The Language of Sentential Logic](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/courses/2012W-4680/handouts/notes1.pdf).  **Bold face** emphasis added by me.

> Let $X$ be a set, and let $\mathscr{P}X=\left\{ A\vert A\subseteq X\right\} $ be the powerset of $X$. Let $\Phi:\mathscr{P}X\to\mathscr{P}X$ be a monotone operation, i.e., for all $A,B\in\mathscr{P}X$, we have $A\subseteq B$ implies $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq\Phi\left(B\right)$.
>
> Definition. We say that a set $A\subseteq X$ is closed under $\Phi$ if $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq A$.
>
> Proposition 1. (a) Let $\left(A_{i}\right)_{i\in I}$ be a family
>   of sets such that each $A_{i}$ is closed under $\Phi$. Then the
>   intersection $A=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}$ is also closed under $\Phi$.
>
> (b) If $B\subseteq X$ is any set, then there exists a smallest subset $\bar{B}\subseteq X$ such that $B\subseteq\bar{B}$ and $\bar{B}$ is closed under $\Phi$.
>
> Proof. (a) Let $i\in I$ be arbitrary. By hypothesis, we have that
>   $A_{i}$ is closed under $\Phi$, so $\Phi\left(A_{i}\right)\subseteq A_{i}$. Since $A\subseteq A_{i}$ for all $i$, we have $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq\Phi\left(A_{i}\right)$
>   by monotonicity of $\Phi$. Hence $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq A_{i}$. Since $i$ was arbitrary, **it follows that $\Phi\left(A\right)=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i},$** therefore $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq A$ and $A$ is closed under $\Phi$.
>
> (b) This is a trivial consequence of (a). Let $\bar{B}$ be the intersection of all sets $A\in\mathscr{P}X$ such that $B\subseteq A$ and $A$ is closed under $\Phi$. By (a), $\bar{B}$ is itself closed under $\Phi$, and it **also contains $A$.** Since it is the intersection of all such sets, it is therefore the smallest with those properties.

There are two conclusions which I am not understanding.  The first is in the proof of (a) where it is stated that $\Phi\left(A\right)=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}.$

Is *equality* justified here, or should it be $\Phi\left(A\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}?$

The second problem is the claim in the proof of part (b) that $\bar{B}$ contains $A$.  Should $A$ be replaced with $B$ in that statement?

Comment: Looking at the link, I don't see the equality statement.

Comment: Indeed.  My mistake.  I had originally wanted to ask about part (b) and transcribed the text for that purpose.  I obviously made a mistake in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality is *not* justified here; once you know this counterexamples are easy to construct by considering the simplest case, where $I=\{i\}$ is a singleton and $\Phi(A_i)$ is a proper subset of $A_i$. Or another simplest case, where $\Phi(A)=\varnothing$ for all $A\subset X$, and $X\neq\varnothing$.

And indeed $A$ should be replaced with $B$ in that part of the statement. As it stands, the statement makes no sense as no particular $A$ has been specified.